# Create a drop down list to view images, then select the wanted image

Tags: php

I have my images in the following folder ../files/images/products. I have tried to select my image folder as follows and would like to select one out of the list.

```
<select name="image1">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <?php 
     $dir = "../files/images/product";//your path
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = $filename;
    }

    sort($files);

       echo "<option value=" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";

?>

</select>
```

This is what I've got, however there is no list showing so can't select anything.
Any help welcome

Comment: At first, your `echo` is not in loop, you should put it in the loop.
I think the best way to achieve it with javascript, select on change and append html with image!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you be able to point me in the right direction as on how to use the java?

Comment: @Ria: Michael said Javascript, not Java, there is a big difference. It's not clear to me what problem Michael is actually suggesting you solve with javascript, producing the list of options is best (and most easily) handled on the server side like you have it, except without the bugs =).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the opening quote on the `value` attribute in the option element.

Vis.:

```
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
```

Your code is looks like `value="`, instead of `value='"`, so it's outputting things like:

```
<option value=path/to/my/file'>path/to/my/file</option>
```

Which isn't valid HTML.

And as one of the commeters pointed out, your echo isn't in the loop, so it will only print a single option, giving the last filename. You want something like this:

```
foreach($files as $filename) {
    echo "<option value=" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
```

Also, you should escape all of the things you print, for instance with `htmlentities`, just to be safe:

```
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = htmlentities($filename);
}
```

So all together, your code might look like this:

```
<select name="image1">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <?php 
    $dir = "../files/images/product";//your path
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = htmlentities($filename);
    }

    sort($files);

    foreach($files as $filename) {
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }

?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="mySelect" name="image1">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
   <?php 
       $dir = "../files/images/product";//your path
       $dh  = opendir($dir);
       while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
           $files[] = $filename;
           echo "<option value=" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
        }

      sort($files);



?>
```

```
   <script> 
     $('#mySelect').on('change', function(e) {
        var address = e.val();
        alert(<?php $dir; ?>+'/'+address);
        });
   </script>
```

This only with alert, but you can find how to append some html element with jQuery or something.